# "way of communicating" vs "way of communication"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I am used to hearing the gerund in phrases that use **"way of..."** Is it wrong to use the noun version of a word that doesn't use "...ing" after "way of"? For example, is it wrong to say the sentences below?

- Sending a letter is not a common way of communication anymore.
- Just reading the class notes is not a good way of preparation.
- Keeping a diary is a good way of introspection.

I think we need to use the gerund instead:

- Sending a letter is not a common way of communicating anymore.
- Just reading the class notes is not a good way of preparing.
- Keeping a diary is a good way of introspecting.

I couldn't find an example of the usage with nouns that don't have the gerund in a dictionary either. Do we always have to use the gerund after "way of"?

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts, there's no real distinction between the noun forms ***communication*** and ***communicating***, but there's [a noticeable difference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way%20of%20communicating%2Cway%20of%20communication%2Cmethod%20of%20communicating%2Cmethod%20of%20communication&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) in the *idiomacy* of certain constructions...

[image]

I'm not sure why ***way*** is so much more likely with the continuous verb ***communicating***, rather than the explicitly "nominal" ("noun-based") derivative ***communication***. I can hardly claim it's because ***a way of*** is inherently "adverbial", given that [***a way of life*** is far more common than ***a way of living***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20way%20of%20life%2Ca%20way%20of%20living&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20way%20of%20life%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20way%20of%20living%3B%2Cc0)